# automatic date format in user input in textbox asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, textbox

i want to have an automatic date format when user enters the date. So far what i got is the automatic comma for price value:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Comma(Num) {
    Num += '';
    Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
    Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
    x = Num.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    return x1 + x2;
}

</script>
```

Can you give me some similar code wherein users can choose a date or when they type it, it automatically adds a slash or something?

Comment: you have tagged c# and javascript. which language are you wanting to use for this?

Comment: C# has a masked textbox option that can automatically format for you.

Comment: @Takarii Isn't that a winforms only control?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod Why aren't you using the jquery datepicker control?   https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats and use it's date formatting functionality.

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod right you are. Totally forgot that :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try the html tag input

```html
<input type="date" runat="server" id="textbox1" />
```

or you can try the AjaxControlToolkit

```html
    <html>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<head>
<!--  your code javascript and Css -->
</head>

<body>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```